# Read json with pyspark - translate pandas code

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

given this json file:

```
path_json_i = '03e4f4f68ed995.json'

def parse_json(json_file):
    """Helper function to share json contents on stackoverflow"""
    with open(json_file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data

parse_json(path_json_i)
```

```
{'cell_type': {'9465819e': 'code', '48c29078': 'code', '27b1c54d': 'markdown'},
 'source': {'9465819e': "#!pip install dlib\n!pip install face_recognition\n#!pip install pillow\nimport numpy as np # linear algebra\nimport pandas as pd # data processing\nimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt\nimport PIL.Image\nimport PIL.ImageDraw\nimport face_recognition\nimport os\nfor dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):\n    for filename in filenames:\n        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))",
  '48c29078': '#data loading\nimage=face_recognition.load_image_file("../input/input-people/friends.jpg")\nface_locations=face_recognition.face_locations(image)\nnum_of_faces=len(face_locations)\nprint("{} face(s) found in this image".format(num_of_faces))\n\npil_image=PIL.Image.fromarray(image)\n\nprint("Pixel locations of faces: ")\n\n#face locations are defined and rectange is drawn\nfor face_location in face_locations:\n    top,left,bottom,right=face_location\n    print("A face is located at pixel location at Top: {} Left: {} Bottom: {} Right: {}".format(top,left,bottom,right))\n    \n    draw=PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)\n    draw.rectangle([left,top,right,bottom],outline="blue",width=3)\n    \npil_image.show()\nplt.imshow(pil_image)\nplt.show()',
  '27b1c54d': 'References:\n\n1.Linkedin Learning-Deep Learning: Face Recognition'}}
```

I'd like to read it using pyspark, without using pandas at all.

Current code with pandas:

```
def read_notebook(path):
    return (
        pd.read_json(
            path,
            dtype={'cell_type': 'category', 'source': 'str'})
        .assign(id=os.path.basename(path))
        .rename_axis('cell_id')
    )

read_notebook(path_json_i)
```

Draft code with pyspark:

```
spark.read.format("json").load(path_json_i).show()
```

Problems with pyspark code:

- reads values as struct
- does not keep the order

Basically, the output should look the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the schema of how you would like the values to be read as.

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("example",StringType(),True)
])

spark.read.schema(schema).format("json").load(path_json_i).show()
```

if you would like the same data types as pandas but in pyspark, checkout this libary
https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/